# Sketch Memory and EEPROM

Tags: eeprom

Since I'm running out of sketch memory, I've decided to use the 512 bytes of EEPROM memory by using `EEPROM.put(addr,variable)`. But every time I use this my sketch memory use in gradually increasing. What am I missing in writing data to EEPROM? Why is the sketch memory use increasing? I'm using Arduino Pro Mini.

Comment: The same answer than to [your previous question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36251/sketch-memory-in-pro)

Comment: @gre_gor  NO  , im asking why is the sketch memory increasing when i use EEPROM.put call .@Mikael Patel has delivered an appropiate answer see that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am i Missing in writing data to EEPROM ? Why is the Sketch memory getting increased ?

Reading and writing to EEPROM will increase program memory size. They are function calls. One way to reduce code is to read/write blocks instead of single bytes. Post some code and we can help you rewrite to something smaller. There are plenty of tricks.